# affine transformation and `imtransform`

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to follow this MATLAB [example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/exploring-slices-from-a-3-dimensional-mri-data-set.html;jsessionid=8f414e7712eae1477a9690816f19).

Please see Step 2, the example used a 128 * 27 matrix M2, and use affine transform to scale and rotate M2, the scale factor is 2.5. However, I expect the size of the result should be 67.5 * 128 (since 27 * 2.5 = 67.5, I do not think it works, but I have no idea how to handle double in this case), the actual result done by MATLAB is 66 * 128.

How to derive the 66 in this case?

I tried to change the scale factor to 2, and the result is 53 * 128, and I expect it to be 54 * 128 since 27 * 2 = 54.

```
load mri
M1 = D(:,64,:,:);
M2 = reshape(M1,[128 27]);
T0 = maketform('affine',[0 -2.5; 1 0; 0 0]);
res = imtransform(M2,T0,'cubic')
size(res) // 66 * 128
```

Comment: btw  `maketform` and `imtransform` are not recommended for usage (if you're not using < R2013x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix with 27 elements has coordinates going from 0 through 26 (these are the coordinates used by `imtransform`). After scaling by 2.5, these coordinates go from 0 through `26*2.5 =` 65. To hold x-coordinates from 0 through 65 you need 66 elements.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I understand your point. But what if I want to scale by 2.6? if you use the same code except changing `T0 = maketform('affine',[0 -2.6; 1 0; 0 0]);`, the result matrix size is `69*128`. So if I follow your point, after scaling by 2.6, these coordinates go from `0` to `26*2.6`=`67.6`. So I guess MATLAB will simply round 67.6 to 68?

Comment: @yiping: honestly I don’t know how it rounds, maybe `round`, maybe `ceil`? Try it out!